# How to upload image from C# application to SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, image-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upload image to server using C#/.NET and storing filename in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054359/upload-image-to-server-using-c-net-and-storing-filename-in-db)

How to upload image from a C# application to SQL Server 2005

Comment: Duplicate of [Upload image to server using C#/.NET and storing filename in DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054359/upload-image-to-server-using-c-net-and-storing-filename-in-db) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698912/asp-net-store-image-in-sql-and-retrieve-for-aspimage or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681124/problems-adding-an-image-to-sql-database-in-asp-net

Comment: Sorry - but this question has been asked **gazillions of times** on this site already! Please **SEARCH** before posting Yet Another Question about images in SQL Server......

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
try
{
const string SQL = "INSERT INTO [BinaryTable] ([FileName], [DateTimeUploaded], [MIME], [BinaryData]) VALUES (@FileName, @DateTimeUploaded, @MIME, @BinaryData)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, Conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MIME", FileToUpload.PostedFile.ContentType);

byte[] imageBytes = new byte[FileToUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Length + 1];
FileToUpload.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BinaryData", imageBytes);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTimeUploaded", DateTime.Now);

Conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
lit_Status.Text = "<br />File successfully uploaded - thank you.<br />";
Conn.Close();
}
catch
{
Conn.Close();
}
}
```

http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/database/upload-files-sql-database-cs.aspx